# 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

I wish to find all records of the current day. I have a field Date of type DATE.
I am getting error on sql server

```
'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

on this line

```
(DATE(EnterDate) = CURDATE() )
```

Comment: DATE is not a function, nor is CURDATE(); `where EnterDate = GETDATE()`

Comment: If `EnterDate` is a `DATE` datatype, why would it need the `DATE()` function (which doesn't exists)

Comment: Have you looked at [Date and Time Data Types and Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)? Neither a `DATE` function or `CURDATE()` are listed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the error states, there is no `DATE` *function* in SQL Server 2008 or 2012 (you tagged both so I'm not sure which you're targeting).  You *can*, however, cast to a `date` type in SQL Server 2008 and above:

```
WHERE EnterDate = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

Note that there's no `CURDATE` function either, so I've translated that to `GETDATE()`

Comment: I know for a fact using `CAST()` function on a date data type column allows your query to be Sargable is it also true in case of `CONVERT()` function ??

Comment: I do not no it for a fact but since `CAST` and `CONVERT` work the same for date/datetime types then it should make no difference.

Comment: constructive criticisim : please have a look here http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: @M.Ali that example shows using `CONVERT` to go from a datetime to a _character_ type, where `CONVERT` _does_ work differently (by supporting multiple formats) and apparently is NOT SARGable.  Accouring to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10854024/1081897) conversion from `datetime` to `date` is sargable.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following condition in your where cluase

```
WHERE CAST(DateColumn AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
              ^------------ Your Column Name with `Date` or 'DateTime'  data type
```

`CURDATE()` is a mysql function, In Sql-Server we have `GETDATE()` function to get current date and time.

Comment: "I have a field Date of type DATE", means no need to cast the column to a `DATE`

Comment: @Lamak I understand that but when a user is trying to use 'CURDATE()' function to get today's date, I find it diffcult to believe that the column he claims to have in `DATE` data type is really in Date data type :)

Answer (score 3):

More efficient one is

```
WHERE EnterDate > DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Thanks @D Stanley @marc_S and @Mihai

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it done by
WHERE EnterDate > Convert(DATETIME,Convert(varchar,DATEADD(DAY,0,GETDATE()),101))

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer but example how to trim the time part from the date time variable

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_manufactured,10) =CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@startdate,10))