# SQL Server, HQL: How to compare SQL server datetime column field to date

Tags: java, sql, datetime, hql

I have following SQL query which i need to make it work in HQL, I tried couple of solutions but none of them work.(Database : SQL server)

```
select t.createdTimeStamp FROM ServiceData t , UserInfo C where C.UserId = t.UserId and  CAST(t.createdTimeStamp AS DATE) = '2016-05-30'
```

I tried following in HQL but none worked, (createdTimeStamp  is of datetime datatype in sql server )

Query:

```
select t.createdTimeStamp FROM ServiceData t , UserInfo C where C.UserId = t.UserId and  CAST(t.createdTimeStamp AS DATE) = '2016-05-30'
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : DATE
```

any suggestion on how to make it work would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried casting the date parameter? `select t.createdTimeStamp FROM ServiceData t , UserInfo C where C.UserId = t.UserId and  CAST(t.createdTimeStamp AS DATE) = CAST('2016-05-30' as date)`

Comment: @vercelli I tried it, got below error **" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode [IDENT] IdentNode: 'createdTimeStamp' {originalText=createdTimeStamp}
] with root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode "**

Comment: maybe this would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471534/no-data-type-for-node-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-tree-identnode-hql

Comment: @vercelli, Thanks for your suggestions, I found help in below URL.[StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973272/date-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer from below StackOverflow URL 
[StackOverflow-date-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973272/date-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name)

I used CONVERT instead of CAST and it worked

Query:`select t.createdTimeStamp FROM ServiceData t , UserInfo C where C.UserId = t.UserId and  CONVERT(date,t.createdTimeStamp)  = '2016-05-30'`

but not sure why CAST didn't work, as per [Hibernate Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) CAST is supported

Answer (score 12):

you have to write the cast command as followed, then it will work

```
cast(t.createdTimeStamp as date)
```

so "cast", "as" and "date" in small caps

Comment: Only `date` needs to be in lowercase - https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-lower-case-data-types/