# SQL: Which way to narrow by DateTime is more efficient?

Tags: sql

I have a query which works well with either `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, [EventStartDateTime], GETDATE()) <= 60
```

or

```
WHERE EventStartDateTime < DATEADD(DY, -60, GETDATE())
```

My question is, which is more efficient? How? And is there a way to measure this in the future to test for myself?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

use the second one,it is [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and can use indexes if present

```
EventStartDateTime < DATEADD(DY, -60, GETDATE())
```

Also `WHERE` clause is not the only place where Sargabilty matters.it can also have an effect on ORDER BY, GROUP BY and HAVING clauses.

> And is there a way to measure this in the future to test for myself?

You can look at the [execution plan](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) ,to see if it is doing a seek or Scan.
This doesn't mean seek is good or scan is bad.when you have index and it is Sargable,it will try* to seek the value,rather than scanning the whole table

Please see below link which has more details on same,as pointed by @AdatheDev in comments..

[Is this date comparison condition SARG-able in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853774/is-this-condition-sargable)

Comment: +1, avoid function calls around columns. Extra reference for this scenario/sargability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853774/is-this-condition-sargable

Comment: yes,I am trying to find Itzik Ben-Gan topic on the same topic

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT <column list> 
  FROM schemaname.tablename -- please always specify schema 
  WHERE EventStartDateTime < DATEADD(DY, -60, GETDATE())
```

The reason this way is efficient is that it makes query more optimized as the index will be put on `EventStartDateTime` . if you dont put index today you may want to use it in future.Thus applying functions like `DATEDIFF()` to the column will always make the expression more complex, so it will always use a less efficient scan (if you use a single search predicate ofcourse).